# AD does not unlock account - even after the Lockout duration is expired

Tags: active-directory

I'm facing a strange problem - domain user accounts are not being unlocked.

These are the Account Lockout Policy settings:
Lockout duration: 30 minutes
Account lockout treshold: 10 invalid logon attempts
Reset lockout account lockout counter afeter: 29 minutes (it was 30 minutes before and it had the same problem)

What is happening is that even after the lockout duration is expired (its been 45 minutes since the lockout time) the account still shows as locked.

Can any of you guys help me?

[Edit]

I'm already using the "Lockout Account Tool" and the tool doesn't show any other Bad Password attempt.

Thanks!

Comment: I just stumbled on somethin related. When I run the PS command Search-ADAccount –LockedOut it's not showing all the locked accounts in my Domain. When I use the LockoutStatus tools, it shows userxyz as locked. If I run the given PS command, it DOES NOT list userxyz. Listing all the properties, it shows LockedOut as false.

Comment: 1. Do you have more then 1 DC? what's the version of the OS and what's the domain\forest level?
 2. Check the following attributes on your DCs (just to ensure that the users are locked out properly):
msDS-ResultantPSO - it should be "CN=PassWord Policy,..." (unless you've a custom password policy object).
msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed - it should be "0x10 = (LOCKOUT)".

Comment: We have more than one DC. We have one Win2003R2 (the domain is in 2003 Mode), one running 2008 R2 and the rest is running 2012 R2.
msDS-User-Account-Control computed is 0x0 for the user. The msDS-ResultantPolic

Comment: We have one Win2003R2 DC (the reason we are running at Win2003 mode), one Win2008R2 DC and the rest of the DCs are Win2012R2.

I can't find the msDS-ResultantPSO on the user account. The msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed is 0x0 ( ). Despite that, the user is still locked.

Comment: Have you checked the msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed attribute on all DCs?
I'm starting to think that this is a replication problem.

Comment: No... I haven't checked. But I think I was misled by the LockoutStatus tool and that my problem was not a problem at all. The tool shows that the account is locked. But Windows lets me login. I'm 90% sure that the accounts were getting locked forever. But now I'm beginning to doubt that. I'm gonna do some more tests.

Comment: Yeap. The problem was that the LockoutStatus tool shows the account as locked but they aren't. :\

Comment: @EliadTech, I consider you to be the most helpful/skilled person that tried to help me. I'd like to give the bounty to you. Can you post an answer so I can award you the points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed is the best indication for user lockout.
As you wrote, though the Lockout Tool showed that the user was locked out the attribute msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed showed otherwise, and the user was actually not locked out.

Seems like the Lockout tool returned a wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a [Lockout tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15201) that you can view Last Bad Pwd and Bad Pwd Count with all your Domain Controllers. This should give you better insight with what is going on. Perhaps the user is still trying to login to the system with the wrong password during the "lock out" period, resetting the timer.

Comment: The original values are taken from this exactly tool.

Comment: Does that tool connects to all Domain Controllers, or just one? Because, AFAICT, account lockout events can happen on another DC, and although the lockout propagates, the event description itself does not propagate.

Comment: It talks to all DCs.

Answer (score 0):

run RSOP.msc and make sure that the proper group policy policies are being applied. Drill down to the lock out settings and make sure they are what you expect them to be.

Comment: I've edited the original question informing that this is a domain account.

Anyway, I don't think RSoP would help. The account is being held locked by the PDC. When I run rsop on it, it shows the appropriate settings. The domain is not applying them.

By the way... when trying to solve the problem I've discovered that when I run RSOP on DCs that are NOT the PDC, the Account Lockout Policy settings show as "Not Defined". I've lost some hours trying to solve that before someone pointing to me that this is normal.

Comment: RSOP.msc is for domain accounts. Have the user that is not getting locked out run it on their workstation and see if the proper group policies are being applied

Comment: How can the user run RSOP.msc if he's locked out of his workstation? Shouldn't the unlock should be done by some DC? The user's workstation should have no influence IMO. Or am I missing something? Anywyay, I tried and it won't show the Computer Settings (Access denied). When I run with and Administrator account it shows the same settings as defined in the Default Domain Policy.

Comment: Have the user run it when they are not locked out. The tool will show you which group policies are being applied to that users account. Maybe the policy with the unlock settings is not being applied to the users. You will have to change whatever permissions you have that are stopping the user from running rsop.msc.

Comment: I've already run it. It shows the default policy, i.e., it should unlock after 30 minutes. And it doesn't.